# load any static site in liferay portal

Tags: liferay, static-site

I am new to Liferay, checking out what all kind of features it provides.

Can we just load any static content website, just by passing its URL to a liferay portal.
It will be something like if portal can behave like a browser, except that it always has to load the same url, and provide navigation within that site.

Comment: Can I also load dynamic contents, like say gmail.com providing it my email id and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, yes you can do that.

You need to install an IFrame Portlet on your page and make its `src` attribute to point to your static site.

Comment: Thanks @adarshr , can I also load dynamic contents, like say gmail.com providing it my email id and password ?

Comment: You can load gmail's login page but you can't expect it to auto-login.

Answer (score 1):

Iframe portlets are designed especially for this purpose. All you need to do is to specify the url and the iframe can be added into the main page.

This is not all. You can also restrict the visibility of the iframes to few roles or users. You can classify users to specific groups and can provide permissions to specific roles so that only they can see the iframe.

You can manually set the size of the iframe or can allow it to adjust to the screen automatically.

There are many more features connected with the iframe portlets in liferay.